# In a Jupyter Notebook how do I split a bulleted list in multiple text cells?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

Suppose I have a bulleted list in Jupyter in a markdown cell like this:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3

Is there a way to convert this one cell list in three markdown text cells?

Comment: Can't you just click the button to create a new cell for each one?

Comment: Yes, but in this case I would have to split the cell in each line. I was thinking some direct way to split it in multiple cells (one per item).

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `-` will split a cell on cursor. Else, cannot process a text of a cell with code unless you're importing a notebook within another notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Use the multi-cursor support functionality. Jupyter supports multiple cursors, similar to Sublime Text.

1. Click and drag your mouse while holding down Alt (Cmmd mac) to
   select the three items,
2. Press the right arrow key to place the multi-cursor next to each
   item,
3. Split cells to create a separate cell per line.